# Two firewalls - redirection after login - fosuser

Tags: security, symfony, redirect, firewall

I have problem with configuring two firewalls in my app based on Symfony2 with the use of FosUserBundle. What I want to have is, secured area for customer on my webiste, at the front level, and secured area for backend. What I had managed to do is, that I really do have two sections (/shop) and  (/admin) and so far they're working but the problem is, that even when I log in on the shop form or admin form it keeps redirecting me to the same direction (/).

**It's my security.yml:**

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CUSTOMER:    ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    admin_secured:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/admin/
        form_login:
          provider: fos_userbundle
          csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
          use_referer:    true
          always_use_default_target_path: true
          default_target_path: /admin/
          login_path: /login
          check_path: /admin/login_check
        logout:
          path:   /admin/logout
        anonymous: false
    main:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
          provider: fos_userbundle
          csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
          default_target_path: /
          target_path_parameter: redirect_url
          login_path: frd_login
        logout:
          path:   fos_user_security_logout
          target: frd_home
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/shop/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/shop/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

**And chunk of my config.yml:**

```
fos_user:
db_driver: propel
firewall_name: main
user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
group:
    group_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\Group
```

Again, when I log in on the **/admin** or **/shop** (<- it is for customers) it's redirecting me to the home (**/**) but from the config I assue that in the **admin section** it should redirect me to **/admin/** and in the **shop section** to the / like it does for every case.

Need some help. Haven't I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change a few things in regards to how you have named your URLs.  I think that Symfony is getting confused because when you go to the admin login page (/login), you are actually using the 'main' firewall, not the 'admin_secured' firewall (notice that in order to use your admin firewall, the url must begin with the `pattern` '/admin').  So try something like this for you firewall settings:

```
firewalls:
    admin_secured:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/admin/
        form_login:
          provider: fos_userbundle
          csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
          #use_referer: true # this is not needed if you always use default target
          always_use_default_target_path: true
          default_target_path: /admin/
          login_path: /admin/login
          check_path: /admin/login_check
        logout:
          path:   /admin/logout
        anonymous: false
    main:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
          provider: fos_userbundle
          csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
          default_target_path: /
          target_path_parameter: redirect_url
          login_path: /shop/login
          check_path: /shop/login_check
        logout:
          path:   fos_user_security_logout
          target: frd_home
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/shop/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/shop/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    # allow all other URLS to be accessed without authentication (may or may not be what you want)
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Give this a shot, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: So you're saying that I ough to create new routes with a prefix of /admin right? In this solutions route /login would not be used. You sure it is good?

Comment: actually for the main firewall you can use the default routes (/login & /login_check) since you use a prefix for the admin's firewall

Comment: Which it is what I'm doing, but the default /admin/login form redirects me to the main page, but it should to the admin backend (f.e. /admin/pages ).

Comment: What it looks like you are doing is using /login for the admin firewall.  You can use /login for the main firewall if you want (it falls under the `pattern` /^), but it won't function as expected if you use it for the admin firewall.

Comment: Well, in fact I know that I'm using main firewall, but I don't know how to use the second one. My main thing is the REDIRECTION after login.

Comment: do you have the /admin/login_check and /admin/login in your routing.yml?  Even though you are not using the route name, they have to be in your routing file